# VSTO Outlook: Create a custom quick access toolbar (QAT) programmatically

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, ribbonx

I have seen that Outlook has a quick access toolbar (QAT).

You can access it doing below:

[image]

And then the QAT appears (see below screenshot, I marked it with a blue rectangle):
[image]

So taken into account that a custom task pane (ctp) have some limitations, for example, you cannot remove title bar nor buttons I was thinking about if it is possible to create a QAT programmatically and embed into it an WPF user control.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. At least there is no trivial way of getting the job done without Windows API functions involved.

The QAT (Quick Access Toolbar) has a predefined set of controls that can be put inside it. Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I am not referring to customize the ribbon.  The links you provided if about customizing the ribbon. I do not want that. Under the ribbon there is a quick access toolbar that you can show or hide through the menu. See my screenshots.. What I would like to do is create a custom quick access toolbar (QAT) and embed there an elementhost which in turn embeds a WPF user control.

Comment: Understood. The first sentences in my post give the answer to that question.

Comment: I supposed that. Customizing Outlook UI and/or create new toolbars is practically imposible, it almost always requires a hack using Windows API functions or hooks when you want to do things a little bit more complicated. Anyway I never undersand why Microsoft can do that (even toolbars without titlebars and buttons, for example yellow toolbars which appears showing information such as add-in disabled, etc.) but they don't allow to do it throught the API.