# How to get the list of commands with position in the Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have added a command button in QAT. I need to call this button from the VBA.

[image: PIC shows the command added]

When I added the command it is on 5th position, so I am able to trigger the command using the below code

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.SendKeys ("%(5)")
```

In the actual scenario, the user might change the position. I want to know using VBA how we can get the list of commands in the QAT with its position, so that I can call the command based on its position.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to get the QAT collection and identify the command by its control id? See [CommandBars object (Office)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars) and [CommandBars.ExecuteMso method (Office)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso).

Comment: I have gone through the links that you shared. I have the tied the sample but in that I am not able to get the QAT collection. It is listing all the command bars but I am not able to find the QAT in that. Also, I directly tries to use the ExecuteMSO method for the command but it is not working

Comment: I think it was superseded by the Fluent UI - See [Overview of the Office Fluent ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/overview-of-the-office-fluent-ribbon) (It links to this from the CommandBars object page, there's a bit note highlighted in purple).

Comment: But my command is a third party com addin which does not have any control id. so that is the reason I added it to the QAT and calling from the VB script

Comment: There are lots of useful links in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74125365/692942). Either way it's not a trivial thing and will require knowledge of Fluent UI XML.

Comment: Firstly, this isn't [tag:vbscript] it's [tag:vba] (two different technologies with differing facets). Secondly, this is not a simple problem and requires a degree of understanding of the technologies involved (Fluent UI). We have provided multiple links and resources to go and research to get a better understanding. Good luck.